# Bug in angular form drop down select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, frontend

I,m working on an angular form and need to resolve a bug.

Here is the issue :

1)- Select type : value-1

2)- Select Data-1 : All Data-1

3)- Select Data-2 : All Data-2

4)- Now change type to : Value-2 (instead of value-1).

The fields of data-1 and data-2 should disappear.

5)- Now select the type again to value-1.

Now click on data-1 or data-2 again...you would see an empty space
again.

**I don't want this empty space here...**

**instead it should be back to --choose one-- 
again...**

I am attaching screenshot and code...please take a look.

[image: Screenshot]

```
<form class="addAlert settings_form" ng-submit="createAlert(newAlert)">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create a New Model</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form_fieldset">

                    <div class="form_item">
                        <label for="title">Name</label>
                        <input name="title" type="text" class="form-input title" required placeholder="Alert Name" ng-model="newAlert.title">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form_item">
                        <label for="alertformat">Type</label>
                        <select class="form-input alertformat"
                                name="alertformat" ng-model="newAlert.alertType"
                                ng-init="newAlert.alertType='Threshold'">
                            <option value="Threshold" selected>Value-1</option>
                            <option value="Pipeline Failure">Value-2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form_item" ng-if="newAlert.alertType !='Pipeline Failure'">
                        <label for="alertformat">Data-1 </label>
                        <select class="form-input alertformat" name="alertformat"
                                ng-model="newAlert.site" required>
                            <option value="" disabled>-- Choose one --</option>
                            <option ng-value="-1">All Data-1</option>
                            <option ng-repeat="item in assetsData" ng-value="{{item.sitename}}">
                                {{item.sitename}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_item" ng-show="newAlert.site" ng-if="newAlert.alertType !='Pipeline Failure'">
                        <label for="alertformat">Data-2</label>
                        <select class="form-input alertformat" name="alertformat" ng-model="newAlert.asset" required>
                            <option value="" disabled>-- Choose one --</option>
                            <option ng-value="-1">All Data-2</option>
                            <option ng-repeat="item in assetsData | filter:newAlert.site" ng-value="{{item.sitename}}">
                                {{item.name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form_item">
                        <label for="alertformat">Color</label>
                        <div class="severity">
                        <input type="radio" class="radioBtnClass" name="numbers" value="Red"checked required>
                        <span>Red</span>
                        </input>

                        <input type="radio" class="radioBtnClass" name="numbers" value="Ember">
                        <span>Blue</span>
                        </input>
                         </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form_item">


                        <label for="users">Users</label>
                        <div class="user_select">
                              <span ng-repeat="user in userList" style="display:block">
                               <input class="alert_user_class" value="{{user.pk}}" type="checkbox">
                                {{user.email}}
                                  </input>
                              </span>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
```

Comment: That empty space comes because the select's model value is not one of its options eg. if your model value is `dummy` and in the select options you don't have an option value `dummy` the empty space comes

Comment: create a plunker or fiddle

Comment: In your case `newAlert.asset` model should always be assigned a value that the underlying select contains as options

Comment: @ShintuJoseph...Any idea that how can i achieve that...if you take a look at the code...then in the dropdown "type" the only directives i have used are ng-model, ng-init....how can i do that On change event select value something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On change event of your 'type' dropdown, you need to assign `$scope.newAlert.site = '';` and `$scope.newAlert.asset = ''` as 'Choose one' option has value Empty String("").

Comment: How can i achieve that...if you take a look at the code...then in the dropdown "type" the only directives i have used are ng-model, ng-init....how can i do that On change event select value something...

Comment: use ng-change to call a function which can do this for you.